# Initializing a char array to be NULL strange behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char compliance[256] = {'\0'};
        if(compliance == NULL)
        {
                printf("compliance is null \n");
                return 0;
        }
        printf("length of compliance %zd \n",strlen(compliance));
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
length of compliance 0


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char compliance[256] = {'\0'};
        memset(compliance,0,256);

        if(compliance == NULL)
        {
                printf("compliance is null \n");
                return 0;
        }
        printf("length of compliance %zd \n",strlen(compliance));
        return 0;
}
```

Output
    length of compliance 0

As many of you have pointed out I wanted to use memset (instead of memcpy).But still don't get why in the second program compliance is not NULL? or in other words How do I make it NULL?

Comment: I'm quite certain you want to use `memset`, not `memcpy`, just as i'm sure It is entirely unneeded given your initializer presence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both programs are broken;

```
    if(compliance == NULL)
```

makes no sense as compliance is never NULL (it is a variable on stack)

In the second part

```
    memcpy(compliance,0,256);
```

copies from source address 0 (NULL) which causes segfault on most platform. You probably want to use `memset` here

Comment: the first line will get optimized out and looks very much like a debugging statement to help remove that case from being the reason for the core dump - the second, ....

Comment: I didn't understand you first comment ? (compliance == NULL) why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: because `compliance` is an array and it is ensured that it is not at a NULL address. You might want `char *compliance = malloc(256)` or so.

Answer (score 2):

`compliance` is an array, not a pointer (An array name are automatically converted to a pointer to the first element in some situations, but **arrays are not pointers**), it will **never** be equal to a null pointer.

The segmentation fault in the second example is caused by the call to `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(compliance,0,256);
```

You are copying from a null pointer. Probably what you want is `memset`.

Answer (score 1):

you probably meant memset

you are copying from address 0 - 256 bytes